# WP multisite restore_current_blog() Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress 3.8.3 and i am using it for multisite.

Wordpress multisite `switch_to_blog()` and `restore_current_blog()` functions works well for single query but in loop `restore_current_blog()` function is not working.

Any one have idea how I will fix it?

Thank You.

Comment: See [restore_current_blog() vs switch_to_blog()](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/89113/12615)

Comment: me checked it but there is no sloution.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use restore_current_blog() for each instance of switch_to_blog().  I just ran into this bug myself.

**Does not work**

```
for [each multi site instance] {
  switch_to_blog()
  // logic
}
restore_current_blog();
```

**Works**

```
for [each multi site instance] {
  switch_to_blog();
  // logic
  restore_current_blog();
}
```

It appears that the switch_to_blog() function does not store the original blog globally so it can be restored outside of a multiple loop. I will be investigating to see if this can be fixed somewhat easily and will try to contribute it to core.

Comment: I had an instance where I needed to use `switch_to_blog(get_current_blog_id());` for some odd reason.